# Disposing of ILoggerFactory in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

In my ASP.NET Core project I have written an extention on `ILoggerFactory` that adds a custom `ILoggerProvider`. (Similar to [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/tree/master/src/NLog.Extensions.Logging))

I'm adding this in `Startup.cs`:

```
loggerFactory.AddRabbitLogger(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(WebLoggerOptions)));
```

The logging is working perfectly, however, it sends messages to RabbitMQ and that means it opens a connection and a channel. These cannot stay open so I close the channel and connection in `Dispose` (`ILoggerProvider` already inherits from `IDisposable`)

My test are successful but the problem is that my test output always shows this error

```
Error while unloading appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015)
```

Another problem is that it takes several seconds after the tests are already finished to show that error so I can't start any new tests.

Is there a way to trigger the dispose of the logger provider in my tests?

Here is the code of my integration test. As you can see, I am doing a dispose in the `TearDown`

**Integration Test**

```
public abstract class TestBase
{
    private TestServer _server;
    protected HttpClient TestHttpClient { get; private set; }

    [SetUp]
    protected void BaseSetup()
    {
        _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>());
        TestHttpClient = _server.CreateClient();
    }       

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        TestHttpClient.Dispose();
        _server.Dispose();
    }
}

public class MyTestClass : TestBase
{
    [Test]
    public async Task SendTest()
    {
        requestUrl = "api/ControllerName/Mehthod";
        var response = await TestHttpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, pardotFormCommand, GetMediaTypeFormatter());
        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);            
    }        
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided any code but my guess would be, could you just not manually dispose the LoggerFactory in teardown?

Comment: Are you using the built-in DI container or something else?

Comment: Also, can you post a snippet of your logger classes and test?

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar and @Dealdiane I added the test code. 
@ChirdeepTomar: I have no access to the ILoggerFactory, only to my `TestServer`. Maybe it's a .NET Core bug that the LoggerFactory is not correctly disposed when I dispose the `TestServer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing my `ILoggerFactory` extensions library.
I also had issues with console applications using this extensions but only when I used more than one service with an `ILogger` implementation.

In the provider (derived from `ILoggerProvider`) there is a `CreateLogger` method. I found out that within one provider you can have multiple loggers (e.g. one for each of your asp.net controllers or for each service in your console app). I mistakenly thought each logger had it's own provider and I only disposed one `ILogger` (the last one).

When I changed my `ILoggerProvider` code to this, I no longer had hangs or errors in my unit tests

```
public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
{
    var companyLogger = new CompanyLogger(categoryName, _loggerOptions);
    _companyLoggers.Add(companyLogger);

    return companyLogger;
}

public void Dispose()
{
    foreach (var logger in _companyLoggers)
    {
        logger.Dispose();
    }           
}
```

In short, if you want to write a custom `ILoggerFactory` with an `ILogger` class that needs to be disposed, you will have to keep the `ILogger` objects in a private list in your `ILoggerProvider` and dispose them all when the `Dispose` is called. If your `ILogger` does not need to be disposed like NLog you don't have to worry about this.